# Differential of matrix $yy^{T}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Consider that $y$ is an $n \times 1$ vector.

How would we go about finding the derivative and differential of of $yy^{T}$?

Comment: The matrix $yy^{T}$ is symmetric with a diagonal of $y_{i}^{2}$. How does this help?

Comment: You can say a bit more about it, I’d say. What do the partial derivatives look like? Another hint: you’re trying to differentiate a product, so...